# Every element in a finite (abelian) group $G$ is an $n$'th power if $\,\gcd(n,|G|)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

How to prove that every element in a finite (abelian) group $G$ is an $n$'th power if $\,\gcd(n,|G|)=1$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft no i dont know  Bezout's identity !!

Comment: Ok, alternative way then. Do you see that $x\mapsto x^n$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to itself?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes i can see that..lets say that x=a^t then
x^n= a^t*n

Comment: Why do you assume $x$ is some power of some other element? That is not what it means to be a homomorphism.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft it means that x↦x^n is  bijection ..am i right ?

Comment: Why? We were going to use the fact that it is a homomorphism to show it is a bijection. I am not really sure which direction you are going.

Comment: Sorry im really confused with this question..i dont know how to start thinking

Comment: Well, can you see why the map I mentioned is a homomorphism?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft no ! can you explain more ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a homomorphism?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft for every a,b $\in$G f(ab)=f(a)f(b)

Comment: Ok, and does this map satisfy that?

Comment: x-->x^n , b-->b^n  ,

x^n*b^n =xb^n,

xb--> xb^n,
@TobiasKildetoft yes

Comment: Good (apart from a few missing parentheses). Now, we would like to show that this map is injective. So what elements are in the kernel?

Comment: e=e^n @TobiasKildetoft
so e is in the kernel

Comment: Right. Can there be any other elements?

Comment: True, but make sure you know why this is the case (i.e. which assumption makes this true).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft let me try to explain why

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft its because (O(G),n)=1

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you don't know it by the name "Bezout Equality", but it is probably the easiest way to go here.

It says that if $\;x,y,\in\Bbb Z\;$  and if $\;\;$ g.c.d. $(x,y)=d\;$ , then there exist $\;m,n\in\Bbb Z\;$ with $\;mx+ny=d$ .

In our case, there exist $\;a,b\in\Bbb Z\;$ s.t. $\;a\mathcal O(G)+bn=1\;$ , and then for **any** $\;g\in G\;$ we get

$$g=g^1=g^{a\mathcal O(G)+bn}=\left(g^{\mathcal O(G)}\right)^a\left(g^b\right)^n=1 x^n=x^n\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;x:=g^b$$

Comment: This answer also shows that you don't need $G$ to be abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my comments expanded into an answer which does not use Bezout's identity (I will in fact at the end use this to prove Bezout's identity purely using group theory).

Let's take a more general setup and prove something a bit stronger:
Let $G$ be any finite group and assume that $n$ is coprime to $|G|$. Then for any $x$ in $G$ there is a $y\in G$ such that $y^n = x$ and such that $y = x^m$ for some $m$.

Proof: Let $H = \langle x\rangle$ and consider the map from $H$ to itself given by $a\mapsto a^n$. This is easily seen to be a homomorphism since $H$ is abelian.

We also see that since $n$ is coprime to $|G|$ it is also coprime to $|H|$ and hence the only element $h\in H$ with $h^n = 1$ must be $1$ (by Lagrange). This means that the map above has trivial kernel, and hence that it is injective.

But since $H$ is finite, this also means that the map is surjective, and hence $x$ must be in the image, which precisely means that there is some $y\in H$ with $y^n = x$ (and since we have $y\in H$ we have $y = x^m$ for some $m$).

To prove Bezout's identity from the above, let two coprime numbers $k$ and $n$ be given. We need to find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ak + bn = 1$. Note that by definition this means that we need to find an integer $b$ such that $bn\equiv 1\pmod{k}$.

To apply the above statement, let $G = \langle x\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order $k$. The above says that there is an integer $m$ such that $(x^m)^n = x$.

But $(x^m)^n = x^{mn}$, and if this equals $x$ then this means that $x^{mn - 1} = 1$, i.e. that $mn - 1$ is divisible by the order of $x$, which is $k$. By definition, this means that $mn - 1\equiv 0 \pmod{k}$ or in other words that $mn\equiv 1\pmod{k}$, so $m$ is the integer we were looking for (the $b$ above).

Comment: Yes, deriving Bezout from Lagrange is one possible way to organize  arithmetic (number theory in $\Bbb Z$), e.g. see the paper of Pierre Samuel that I cite [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151530/242), which examines all permutation of few foundational theorems as bases for arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

[As in $U(\Bbb Z/m),\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) it's easy to take $n$'th roots in a group if $\,n\,$ is coprime to the group order $\:\!|G|$.

**Theorem** $ $ Compute $\,n$'th root in group $\,G\,$ by raising to power $\frac{1}n\!\pmod{\!|G|}\,$ if $\,\gcd(n,|G|)\! =\! 1$

Let $\,\color{#0a0}{f=|G|}.\,$ [By Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) $\,\gcd(n,f)\!=\!1$  $\Rightarrow \exists\:\!  n' \equiv \frac{1}n\equiv n^{-1}\!\pmod{\!f},\, $ so  $\ \color{#c00}{nn' = 1 + fj}\,$ so
$$ \bbox[8px,border:2px solid #96f]{{a^{\Large\color{c00} n} = b \iff a =  b^{\:\!\Large n'},\ \ n' \equiv \frac{1}n\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!f}}}\qquad$$

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\ \ \   &b = a^{\large n}\,\Rightarrow\, b^{\large n'}\! = a^{\large \color{#c00}{nn'}}\! = a^{\large\color{#c00}{1+fj}} = a(\color{#0a0}{a^{\large f}})^{\large j} = a\\
&a = b^{\large n'}\!\Rightarrow\, a^{\large n} = b^{\large\color{#c00}{n'n}} = \,b^{\large\color{#c00}{1+fj}} = \,b(\color{#0a0}{b^{\large f}})^{\large j} = b \end{align}$

because, $ $ by [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)#Applications),  $\ \color{#0a0}{f=|G|\,\Rightarrow\, a^f = 1 = b^f}$

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the OP. In fact, the converse of this statement is also true, i.e., if every element in a finite group $G$ is a $n$-th power, then $\gcd(n,|G|) =1$.

We prove this by contradiction. First we note that the map $G \to G: g \mapsto g^n$ is surjective by assumption. Since $G$ is finite, this map is also injective. Now we suppose that $\gcd(n,|G|)>1$, then there's a prime number $p$ dividing both $n$ and $|G|$. By Cauchy's theorem, there is an element $x\in G$ with order $p$. Since $x$ is a $n$-th power (by assumption), there is $y\in G$ such that $x = y^n$, and $|y^n|=p$, i.e., $y^{np}=(y^p)^n = 1$. Because the map $g\mapsto g^n$ is injective and $1^n = 1$, we know that $y^p=1$. This forces $|y|=p$. Therefore, $y^n = y^{p\cdot (n/p)} =1$. But then this contradicts the fact that $|y^n| = p$ and we proved the claim.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Interesting additional lemma, +1. "$x$ is a $p$-th power" should be "$x$ is a $n$-th power" though. I can't suggest that edit because of the minimum limit of six characters.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change it now