# If gcd$(a,b) = 1$, then I want to prove that $\forall c \in \mathbb{Z}$, $ax + by = c$ has a solution in integers $x$ and $y$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If gcd$(a,b) = 1$, then I want to prove that $\forall c \in \mathbb{Z}$, $ax + by = c$ has a solution in integers $x$ and $y$.

This is what I was attempting or trying:

Let $d =$ gcd$(a,b)$.

$d|a \Rightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $a = dk$.

$d|b \Rightarrow \exists l \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $b = dl$

Substituting these in we get $dkx + dly = c \Rightarrow d(kx + ly) = c \Rightarrow d|c$ and $(kx+ly)|c$.

I'm not sure if this proves it or not. The help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want to use that $d={\rm gcd}(a,b)=ax+by$ for some $x,y$. If $d=1$; then $c=a(cx)+b(cy)$ for any $c$.

Comment: Give someone else a chance to answer,Pedro,sheesh! lol j/k

Comment: Well, if $gcd(a,b)=1$, there exists $u$,$v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1=au+bv$, so $c=a(cu)+b(cv)$ and $x=cu$, $y=cv$ are integers.

Comment: Do you already know Bezout's identity  $\,\gcd(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\, ax+by = 1\,$ for some integers $\,x,y\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have proved that if $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, and $c=ax+by$, then $d\mid c$. That is not at all what we want to show.

The result will be easy once we prove:

*Lemma:* If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $as+bt=1$.

Taking the Lemma for granted temporarily, note that if $as+bt=1$ then $a(cs)+b(ct)=c$, so we can take $x=cs$ and $y=ct$ to prove our result. But the hard part is

*Proof of Lemma:* We sketch the standard proof. Let $K$ be the set of all positive integers that  can be represented in the form $au+bv$, where $u$ and $v$ range over the integers. The set $K$ is non-empty, so has a smallest positive element $k$.  So there is a $u_1,v_1$ such that $k=au_1+bv_1$. We show that $k=1$. That will complete the proof.

Suppose to the contrary that $k\gt 1$. The number $k$ cannot divide *both* of $a$ and $b$, for if it did we would violate $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Without loss of generality we may assume $k$ does not divide $a$. Then $a=qk+r$, for some integers $q$ and $r$ such that $0\lt r\lt k$.

But then
$$r=a-qk=a-q(au_1+bv_1)=a(1-qu_1)+b(-qv_1).$$
Since $0\lt r\lt k$, this contradicts the fact that $k$ is the *smallest* positive integer of the shape $au+bv$.

Comment: A nice way to view the proof: $\,K\,$ is closed under subtraction $> 0,\,$ i.e. $\,j>k\in K\,\Rightarrow\,j-k\in K.\,$ Thus $\,K\,$ is closed under mod (remainder), since this arises by repeatedly subtracting $\, k\,$ from $\,j,\ $ i.e. $\, j\ {\rm mod}\ k\, =\, j - q\,k\,=\,j-k-k\cdots -k.\,$ Therefore the least $\,k\in K\,$ divides every $\,j\in K\,$ (else $\,0\ne j\ {\rm mod}\ k\in K\,$ is smaller than $\,k).\ $ Thus $\,a,b\in K\,\Rightarrow\, k\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,k = 1,\,$ by $\,\gcd(a,b)= 1.\ $ Further discussion is in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242)

Answer (score 1):

since $(a,b)=1$ we can find integers $p,q$ so that the $2 \times 2$ matrix:
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ p & q \end{pmatrix}
$$
has determinant $1$. let $d$ be an arbitrary integer, and consider the equation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ p & q \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
$$
this has solution
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}q & -b \\ -p & a \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
$$
i.e.
$$
x = qc-bd \\
y = ad - pc \\
$$
you may verify that, whatever the value of $d$, we have:
$$
ax + by = aqc - abd +bad -bpc = (aq-bp)c = |M|c = c
$$

Comment: Simpler: scale the Bezout identity $\,1 = qa-pb\,$ by $\,c\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Another way: $ $ by [Euler $\phi$,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $\,\ \begin{align}(a,b)=1\\ n= \phi(b)\ \end{align} $ $\, \Rightarrow\ \begin{align} c\,&\equiv\, a^{\large n}c\!\pmod{\! b}\\  {\rm i.e.}\,\ \ c\,&=\, a (a^{\large n-1}c)+b\,y \end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1140067/242) for  alternative proofs. What works best in any given context depends on the *order* that the basic theorems are presented. There are many possible orders, e.g. see Pierre Samuel's [Sur l'organisation d'un cours d'arithmétique,](http://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1967:13::92) L'Enseignement Mathématique, 13 (1967) 223-231, where he examines in detail approaches based on all possible permutations of a few fundamental theorems (one uses [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) to derive the gcd Bezout equation, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1068984/242)).

**Update** $\ $ The linked answer's thread has been deleted so I repost the answer below.

---

**Hint** $\ $ Use [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $\rm \,(c,m)=1\,\Rightarrow\,c^{\large \phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m,\,$ or use [Bezout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout%27s_identity) as follows:

$$\rm \exists\, x\in\Bbb Z\!:\  cx\equiv b\!\!\!\pmod{\! m}\!\iff\! \exists\, x,y\in\Bbb Z\!:\ cx\!+\!my = b\!\overset{\rm\ Bezout}\iff\!\gcd(c,m)\mid b$$

Or use the following

**Theorem** $\ $ The following are equivalent for integers $\rm\:c,\, m.$

$(1)\rm\ \ \ gcd(c,m) = 1$
$(2)\rm\ \ \ c\:$ is invertible $\rm\,(mod\ m)$
$(3)\rm\ \ \ x\to cx+d\:$ is $\:1$-$1\:$ $\rm\,(mod\ m)$
$(4)\rm\ \ \ x\to cx+d\:$ is onto $\rm\,(mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\  (1\Rightarrow 2)\  $ By [Bezout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout%27s_identity) $\rm\, gcd(c,m)\! =\! 1\Rightarrow cd\!+\!km =\! 1\,$ for $\rm\,d,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ $\rm\Rightarrow cd\equiv 1\!\pmod{\! m}$
$(2\Rightarrow 3)\ \ \ \rm cx\!+\!d \equiv cy\!+\!d\,\Rightarrow\,c(x\!-\!y)\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,x\!-\!y\equiv 0\,$ by multiplying by $\rm\,c^{-1}$
$(3\Rightarrow 4)\ \  $ Every $1$-$1$ function on a finite set is onto (pigeonhole).
$(4\Rightarrow 1)\ \ \ \rm x\to cx\,$ is onto, so $\rm\,cd\equiv 1,\,$ some $\rm\,d,\,$ i.e. $\rm\, cd+km = 1,\,$ some $\rm\,k,\,$ so $\rm\gcd(c,m)=1$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664094/242) for a conceptual proof of said Bezout identity for the gcd.