# Proving multiplicative inverse of modulo $m$ exists when $\gcd(m,x)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

I basically don't understand the way the proof is given in my text as well as some references online. They basically do the same thing.

**THEOREM**: Let $m,x$ be positive integers such that $\gcd(m, x) = 1$. Then $x$ has a multiplicative inverse
modulo $m$, and it is unique, $\mod m $.

Now,  this is a sufficient and  necessary condition,  **but  let's just look  at the  proof  that it is the sufficient condition which is given in my texts.**

**Proof**:
Consider the sequence of m numbers $0,x,2x,...,(m−1)x$. We claim that these are all distinct,$\mod m$. Since there are only $m$ distinct values modulo $m$, it must then be the case that $ax = 1 \mod m$,  for
exactly one $a (\mod m)$. This a is the unique multiplicative inverse.
To verify the above claim, suppose that $ax = bx \mod m$ for two distinct values $a,b$ in the range $0 ≤ a,b ≤
m−1$. Then we would have $(a−b)x = 0 \mod m$, or equivalently, $(a−b)x = km$ for some integer $k$ (possibly
zero or negative). But since $x$ and $m$ are relatively prime, it follows that $a−b$ must be an integer multiple
of $m$. This is not possible since $a,b$ are distinct non-negative integers less than $m$.

What I don't see particularly in this proof is the connection betweent the $\gcd$ being one and the existence of the multiplicative  inverse. What I do  see instead is that the proof that the multiplicative inverse is  unique.

What is the connection of  the $\gcd$ being $1$ and  the existence of  the multiplicative  inverse $\mod m$?

Comment: You may find illuminating the $4$ equivalent characterizations in the [Theorem here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151530/242)

Comment: Duplicate of [If $q$ is coprime to $a$ then $a\mid (nq-1),\,$ i.e. $q$ is invertible mod $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326598/if-q-is-coprime-to-a-then-a-mid-nq-1-i-e-q-is-invertible-mod-a) $\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above proof shows that the set $\{0,x,2x,\dots,(m−1)x\}=\{ax \mid a = 0,\dots,m-1\}$ has *distinct* elements under $\mod{m}$.  Therefore, $|\{0,x,2x,\dots,(m−1)x\}| = m$, therefore, this set under $\mod{m}$ contains all representatives in $\mod{m}$.  In particular, there exists $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, so there exists $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $ax = 1 + km$.  This should give you $ax - km = 1$, so that $\gcd(a,m) = 1$ by Bezout's Identity.

Comment: The proof should'd mentioned this hint. :-)

Comment: The moral of this story is to *never* overlook a result that *counts* something.

Answer (score 2):

The key is in the claim that $0, x, 2x, \ldots, (m-1)x$ are all distinct. If this weren't true then
$(a-b)x = km$ for some $a,b<m$ and some integer $k$. This says that $m$ divides $(a-b)x$. Since $x$ and $m$ are relatively prime, $m$ must divide $a-b$.

It might help to think in terms of prime factorization. If $m$ divides $(a-b)x$ then all of the prime powers in $m$ must live in the product $(a-b)x$. $m$ and $x$ being relatively prime says that none of the primes dividing $m$ divide $x$, so all of the prime powers making up $m$ must come from $(a-b)$. This shows that $m$ divides $a-b$. Does the rest of their proof make sense?

Comment: thank you for your reply. But, again, you're not stating what does the proof have to do with the GCD being one and as a consequence the multiplicative inverse being existent. You're concluding that m divide a-b, and I also understand that a =! b, but what does that have to do with the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: "Relatively prime" means the same thing as having a GCD of 1. The conclusion that $m$ divides $a-b$ comes from the GCD being 1 (in the way I described above). Once you have that $0, x, 2x, \ldots, (m-1)x$ are distinct, you must have that $ax \equiv 1\pmod{m}$ for some $a$.