# Verifying proof for the following gcd question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove that for all nonzero integers $a$ and $b$, if $\gcd(|a|,|b|)=1$ then for all integers $c$, if $a\mid bc$ then $a\mid c$.

Given that $\gcd(|a|,|b|)=1$ then there exists $m,n\in Z$ such that $am+bn=1$ which implies $acm+bcn=c$.

Given $a|bc$, to show $a\mid c$. Now, $a\mid acm$ and $a\mid bcm$ as $a\mid bc$ implies $a\mid acm +bcn = c$. Therefore $a\mid c$.

Is my proof sufficient? Thank you!

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: thank you @ChrisCuster

Comment: That's the common Bezout-based proof of Euclid's Lemma. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) for a few other forms.

Comment: You should also be able to do it with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Yes, unless it's on the way to proving the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @EthanBolker Indeed. See Pierre Samuel's interesting pedagogical article [cited here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151530/242) on the many possible  paths we can take to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic in an elementary course. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973557/242) and its links for various "direct" proofs of Euclid's Lemma using only Division (with Remainder), i.e. in arithmetical "assembly language".