# If $a^3=e$, then $a$ has a square root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a^3=e$, then $a$ has a square root.

I have that $a^3=aaa=e$ and applying $a^{-1}$ twice on both sides of the equation gives us $a=a^{-1}a^{-1}$ and so $a=(a^{-1})^2$. Thus $a$ has a square root.

Is this correct? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: This is fine.${}$

Comment: Another way: $(a^2)^2 = a^4 = a$.  (This one will also work in monoids, not just in groups.)

Comment: Your way is fine.  I'd have noticed first though that if $a^3 = e$ and $a^4 = ea=a$ and $(a^2)^2 = a$.  Note $a^{-1} = a^2$.

Comment: Same as in the [dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064817/let-g-to-be-finite-abelian-group-of-order-og-let-n-to-be-prime-number-and), $\,a^{\large \color{#c00}3} = 1\Rightarrow a^{\large 1/2} = a^{\large 1/2\bmod 3} = a^{\large 1/-1\bmod 3} = a^{\large -1}\,$ is a square root of $\,a\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt is correct, and as mentioned there is the other proof, that $a^3 = e$ implies $a^4 =(a^2)^2 =a$.

A more general statement is true, and is easy to prove.

> If $G$ is a finite group of odd order then every element of $G$ has a *unique* square root.

Proof : Let $|G| = 2n-1$, then if $a = g^2 = h^2$ for two elements $g,h$, then $(g^{2})^{n} = (h^2)^n$ implies $g^{2n} = h^{2n}$ implies $g=h$ by Lagrange's theorem. Thus, $a$ has a unique square root.

Finally, the map $S : G \to G$ given by $S(x) = x^2$ is an injective map between finite sets of the same size, hence a surjective map. The result follows.

---

To apply this to your question, if $a^3 = e$ then the cyclic group generated by $a$ has three elements , and you apply the above statement to conclude.

(TASK : Prove that if $G$ is a group such that every element of $G$ has odd order, then every element of $G$ has a square root, using the method above).

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to FAQs. Rather, help to organize and improve the prior answers (there are *many* on this and related topics).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for the remark, I will be careful next time.